# Draw line chart and highlight minimum point in matplotlib or seaborn and with the help of pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a data frame as shown below

df

```
Threshold   Total_cost
0.7         150040
0.8         150843
0.9         149410
1           148981
1.1         149163
1.2         150017
```

By using above df I would like to plot a line graph in python with y axis as Total cost and x axis as Threshold.

Where y axis range could be `148000` to `151000`.
And I also wants to highlight the point where Total_cost is minimum.
In this case which is `(1, 148981)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `idxmin` to locate the row with minimum cost:

```
ax = df.plot(x='Threshold')

(df.loc[[df['Total_cost'].idxmin()]]
   .plot.scatter(x='Threshold', y='Total_cost',
                 color='r', ax=ax)
)
```

Output:

[image]